# SAAS for user registration on web site

Tags: registration, saas, web-services

Can anyone recommend a service which we can use to handle user registration on a website.

I know of services like Wufoo, but they just offer forms.
What we are looking for is a service which we can embed which has all the features like user signup, password recovery, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Single Sign-On solutions are probably your best bet. The following are all OpenID providers (though some services, like Janrain, PingIdentity, onelogin, etc. support multiple protocols, and Facebook Connect also has its own API):

- Janrain
- myOpenID
- Google
- myOneLogin
- PingIdentity
- onelogin
- Facebook Connect

Janrain is probably the most comprehensive service, followed by PingIdentity and onelogin. All 3 offer turnkey solutions for enterprise businesses. With Google and Facebook Connect, it's more of a *integrate yourself* solution for developers.

There are also these alternative SSO providers using different protocols:

- CoSign
- Pubcookie
- WebAuth
- OpenAthens (for government and educational institutions only, I think)

But most of these will probably be harder to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Connect and Twitter offer 2 simple choices for implementing these features without having to build your own user registration system.

OpenID is another option, allowing people to sign in with an account that is based on OpenID (such as their Google account). However, the concept of OpenID is very confusing for non-technical users.

Answer (score 1):

Found this question while searching is there a user registration service like jotform or wufoo, think i got your point. I would suggest you to dig into jotform where you can create relatively complex flows with Mailchimp and POST support. Btw unfortunately could not find exactly what i am looking for still, good luck..